# how to bind drawable files to variables - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I'm developing an app which needs to set some wallpapers on the phone from my drawables folder, but I have to write code for each file separately. this is my code:

```
    fun setWallpaper(number:Int) {

  val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context)
  val i: Int = when(number){
      0->R.drawable.wp1.toInt()
      1->R.drawable.wp2.toInt()
      2->R.drawable.wp3.toInt()
      3->R.drawable.wp4.toInt()
      4->R.drawable.wp5.toInt()
      5->R.drawable.wp6.toInt()
      6->R.drawable.wp7.toInt()
      7->R.drawable.wp8.toInt()
      8->R.drawable.wp9.toInt()
      9->R.drawable.wp10.toInt()
      else->0
  }
   wallpaperManager.setResource(i)
 
}
```

the number variable is the position I get from recyclerview. but this does not seem like a good way and is not dynamic, I can't write a line of code for each file when I have 100 files or so
is there a way that I can use to kinda connect a variable to filenames? how can I do it?
thanks a lot

Comment: I updated my answer to be more complete. You will probably prefer the other way if you have many files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listOf` and then retrieve by index. There's no reason to use `toInt()` on each element because they already are Ints. You can import the members of `R.drawable` using `*` so don't have to retype it.

```
import com.mypackage.myapp.R.drawable.*

//...

fun setWallpaper(number: Int) {
  val wallpapers = listOf(wp1, wp2, wp3, /* ... */ wp10)
  val resource = if (number in wallpapers.indices) wallpapers[number] else 0
  WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).setResource(resource)
}
```

If you have very many of them and a consistent naming scheme, then you can retrieve by name. This is slightly slower because it uses reflection under the hood, but that's trivial to retrieve only one element.

```
fun setWallpaper(number: Int) {
  val resource = context.resources.getIdentifier("wp${number + 1}", "drawable", context.packageName)
  WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).setResource(resource)
}
```